# angularJS: how to specify DOM elements (selectors)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, jquery-selectors

Generally, the question is: **how to use DOM selectors in AngularJS**?

More deeply: what is the recommended way to specify a DOM element, where some action should be done? Let's say, I've got a plugin or a component that does some magical stuff (animations, executes a flow, embeds something, etc.) and **I need to decide where it will happen in the runtime**?

I'll compare it with Backbone. Angular is more declarative, whereas Backbone is imperative. In Backbone there is jQuery (or sth alternative), each Backbone.View has `el.$`, which is a jQuery selector engine that is bound not to global DOM, but to the View's sub-DOM tree. This is faster (no need to search elements globally), easier to maintain (won't find any DOM element outside the View) and convenient. I can pass the selector, such as `#id` or `.class` during runtime. And execute or open something manually, because **Backbone is imperative**.

Now how about angular? Let's say I want to start a big and complex user-interface process: it consists of few forms and few views, navigated forward step by step, and eventually finished with ending view (job successful or sth alike). When one view is finished, it is reloaded (overlay/spinner) and another is loaded. I want to embed it into a specified DOM element, but I would like to define it during runtime, not to embed it as angular attribute. How does that conform to *angular philosophy*?

Comment: I think you are searching for this: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile

Comment: @slotomo what `$compile` does is creating a function that can generate parametrized HTML. So it's an alternative to handlebars, _.template and many, many more. What I'm looking for in this question is a *DOM selector*. In other words, I don't get your point.